# 5 left joins cause query to time out, mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, query-optimization

The whole point is to get all artist records, and any matching records in 5 other tables.

There are maybe 50,000 artist records.

I plan on creating a view out of this statement and then using it to keep a sugarcrm db up to date.

Any help is hugely appreciated.

here is the SQL statement,

```
 SELECT 
 /*foreign keys*/
 band_profiles.id AS 'BP_ARTIST_ID', 
 bandsintown_artists.id AS 'BID_ARTIST_ID',
 contacts.id AS 'CONTACTS_MGMT_ID',
 facebook_stats.id AS 'FB_STATS_ID',
 outbound_links.id AS'OUTB_LINKS_ID',

 /*high level*/
 band_profiles.name AS 'ACCOUNT_NAME', 
 band_profiles.description AS 'ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION', 
 band_profiles.bandsintown_status AS 'BIT_STATUS',
 band_profiles.created_at AS 'DR_CREATED_DATETIME', 
 band_profiles.updated_at AS 'DR_UPDATED_DATETIME',

 /*account mgmt fields*/
 contacts.description AS 'ACCOUNT_MGMT_CONTACT',
 contacts.contact_type AS 'ACCOUNT_MGMT_TYPE',
 contacts.custom_contact_type AS 'ACCOUNT_MGMT_TYPE_C',

 /*account web & social*/
 band_profiles.website_url AS 'WEBSITE_URL', 
 band_profiles.twitter_url AS 'ACCOUNT_TWITTER_URL',
 band_profiles.facebook_url AS 'ACCOUNT_FACEBOOK_URL', 
 band_profiles.facebook_page_id AS 'ACCOUNT_FACEBOOK_ID',
 band_profiles.facebook_like_count AS 'ACCOUNT_FACEBOOK_LIKES',
 facebook_stats.like_count AS 'FB_TOTAL_LIKES',
 facebook_stats.share_count AS 'FB_TOTAL_SHARES',
 facebook_stats.comment_count AS 'FB_TOTAL_COMMENTS',
 facebook_stats.click_count AS 'FB_TOTAL_CLICKS',
 outbound_links.target_url AS 'OUTBOUND_LINK',
 outbound_links.link_type AS 'OUTB_LINK_TYPE',

 bandsintown_artists.facebook_tour_dates_url AS 'ACCOUNT_FB_TOUR_DATES'


 FROM band_profiles
 LEFT JOIN bandsintown_artists
 ON band_profiles.id = bandsintown_artists.band_profile_id
 LEFT JOIN contacts
 ON band_profiles.id = contacts.id
 LEFT JOIN facebook_stats
 ON band_profiles.id = facebook_stats.band_profile_id
 LEFT JOIN outbound_links
 on band_profiles.id = outbound_links.band_profile_id
 GROUP BY band_profiles.id
 LIMIT 10
```

this is the error code I am getting

```
 Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 600.000 sec
```

Comment: Why do use `GROUP BY` without any aggregation?

Comment: `LIMIT 10` without `ORDER BY` is kinda pointless.

Comment: Please run an `EXPLAIN` on your query and show us the result.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for each table in the query so we can examine the columns' data types and any indexes you have.

Answer (score -1):

If you are the sysadm, you can increase the mysql timeout values.  see http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server

Depending on the number of deleted entries in your db, you might see significant memory/time savings in this query by pruning deleted entries in your JOIN queries

also limit your final output by band_profiles.deleted = 0

```
LEFT JOIN bandsintown_artists
 ON (band_profiles.id = bandsintown_artists.band_profile_id AND bandsintown_artists.deleted = 0)
 LEFT JOIN contacts
 ON (band_profiles.id = contacts.id AND contacts.deleted = 0)
 LEFT JOIN facebook_stats
 ON (band_profiles.id = facebook_stats.band_profile_id AND facebook_stats.deleted = 0)
 LEFT JOIN outbound_links
 on (band_profiles.id = outbound_links.band_profile_id AND outbound_links.deleted = 0)
WHERE band_profiles.deleted = 0
```